# profiler queries count always empty

Tags: symfony, profiler

I follow this documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html

But `$profile->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount()` always equals 0

Here is an extract of my test :

```
class MyControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    protected ?EntityManagerInterface $em = null;
    protected ?KernelBrowser $client = null;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient([], [
            'HTTP_USERNAME' => 'myUser',
            'HTTPS' => true
        ]);
        $this->em = $this->client->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testRandomNumber(): void
    {

        $this->client->enableProfiler();

        $this->client->request(
            Request::METHOD_GET,
            '/api/myRoute/find'
        );
        $this->client->enableProfiler();
        self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_OK);

        // check that the profiler is enabled
        if ($profile = $this->client->getProfile()) {
            $count = $profile->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount();
            // check the number of requests
            $this->assertLessThan(
                10,
                $count
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and my packages/test/web_profiler.yaml (I enabled all just to be sure)

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

framework:
    profiler: { enabled: true, collect: true }
```